# How to create event listeners for icons?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i have the code:

```
<a  class="work__icon-container"><i class="fas fa-search work__img-icon"></i></a>
```

When i create the event listener for class "work__icon-container", my event listener doesn't work:

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(event){
 if (event.target.classList.contains('work__icon-container')){
  console.log('works!')
 }
})
```

Of course, i found, that when i click to the icon, i get:

```
 <i class="fas fa-search work__img-icon"></i>
```

or:

```
<path fill="currentColor" d="M505 442.7L405.3 343c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H372c27.6-35.3 44-79.7 44-128C416 93.1 322.9 0 208 0S0 93.1 0 208s93.1 208 208 208c48.3 0 92.7-16.4 128-44v16.3c0 6.4 2.5 12.5 7 17l99.7 99.7c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l28.3-28.3c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6.1-34zM208 336c-70.7 0-128-57.2-128-128 0-70.7 57.2-128 128-128 70.7 0 128 57.2 128 128 0 70.7-57.2 128-128 128z"></path>
```

How to create event listener for all elements of class = "work__icon-container"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method of a DOM Element.

It will work up the DOM looking for the element that you query. `closest` works the same like `querySelector` as you can type CSS like selectors to find elements.

If `closest` has a hit it returns the element. If no element is found it will return null.

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(event){
  const workContainer = event.target.closest('.work__icon-container');
  if (workContainer !== null {
    console.log(workContainer);
  }
});
```

With `closest` you can work with the element you are trying to select instead of only checking if it is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to add the event handler to the actual element itself, it would work, and there is no need to check the classlist:

```
document.querySelector('a.work__icon-container').addEventListener('click', ...
```

Of course, there's probably a reason why you want to attach the listener higher up.  In this case, it isn't enough to check the target's classlist, as the target being clicked might be inside what you want.  Instead, see if it matches the selector, or a child of that selector.

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!e.target.matches('.work__icon-container, .work__icon-container *')) {
    return;
  }
  console.log('It works!');
});
```

Comment: It awesome! But, maybe you can say: if i want to take some parameters from work__icon-container parent, what should i do? because the parent of event.target changes: some times it  <i class="fas fa-search work__img-icon"></i>, sometimes <a  class="work__icon-container">

Comment: To take parameters from the element (for instance id) you do: e.target.id. And from the parent you do: e.target.parentNode.id.